# NSFetchRequest with subentities - searching within the subentities

Tags: ios, search, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to figure out if I can do two kinds of searches on my data model using the same fetch request, but with different predicates depending on whether the search input is a letter or number.

So I have a Contact entity, and a Phone entity. The contact has a list of phoneNumbers (work, cell, etc). So what I want to do is have a fetch request that includes the subentities which I think will bring back the contact and its list of phoneNumbers? Then depending on whether the user entered a letter or a digit, search either the contact name or within the phone numbers. I'm not sure how to do the latter part in a predicate though, or if it's even possible, given it's a list of numbers and not just one (otherwise I think I could do 'contact.number').

If it's NOT possible, I'm not sure what else to try. I display the results using the contact name. So if I have a completely different fetch request for the Phone scenario, I can bring back all the phone numbers - but then I would have to do a second fetch to get all the contacts tied to those phone numbers in order to be able to display the names of the results? That seems really slow. I have 40k contacts.......

Comment: How are you modeling the phoneNumbers relationship?

Comment: In my data model I specify that Contact has a relationship to Phone and it's labeled as phoneNumbers.

Comment: So Contact has a to-many relationship with Phone called phoneNumbers... what is the inverse, and is it also to-many or is it to-one?

Comment: No, it doesn't have an inverse relationship. Perhaps that is part of my problem? It should be to-one I suppose, since even if two people had the same phone number it would be two entries in the Phone table.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to search for all contacts that have a phone number which starts with a given number?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I already have a search for all contacts whose name starts with a given letter (or letters). I am trying to use the same search box and decide dynamically based on the text input which search to use.

Comment: What about `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY phoneNumbers.number BEGINSWITH %@", theNumber];` ?

Comment: That seems to be bringing back all results and not actually filtering on the phone number. I'll double check it and report back.

Comment: Yeah that just brings back ALL contacts.

Comment: I tried it with myself with a test project and there it worked...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15821/discussion-between-martin-r-and-michaela)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following predicate on "Contact" can be used to get all contacts that have a phone number starting with the given prefix:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY phoneNumbers.number BEGINSWITH %@", numberPrefix];
```